# Django Internationalization (I18N) not changing text

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

I created an simple website to test internationalization, but I can't make it work the way I wanted. I would like to change messages in my views.py without checking the **request.LANGUAGE_CODE** (which is showing correctly).

I can go to the urls with prefix **/en/** and **/pt-br/** but they don't change the text in the template.

I tried running

```
django-admin makemessages --locale=pt_BR
```

I changed the lines

```
#: mytest/views.py:7
msgid "Welcome to my site."
msgstr "Bem vindo ao meu site."
```

ran

```
django-admin compilemessages --locale=pt_BR
```

PS: (even though it is wrong, I tried django-admin makemessages/compilemessages --locale=pt-br as well)

What I changed in **settings.py** (added my app, added locale middleware, added some internalization settings)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mytest'
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale/translations/'),
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
LANGUAGES = [
  ('pt-br', _('Portuguese')),
  ('en', _('English')),
]

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

def index(request):
    print(request.LANGUAGE_CODE) #this shows correctly the prefix in the url
    output = _("Welcome to my site.")
    context = {"test_translate": output}
    return render(request, "mytest/index.html", context)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from mytest import views

urlpatterns = [
]
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my path was not correct. I believe the extra slash was wrong... I deleted /translations/ from the LOCALE_PATH and it is working now.

```
LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
]
```

Then I run

```
django-admin compilemessages -l pt_BR
```

Modify the *.po generated and run

```
django-admin compilemessages -l pt_BR
```

I also renamed **en-us** to **en** in `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'`

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this steps.

1) Create folder `'locale'` in root.

2) Add middeleware

```
.....
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
....
```

3) In settings.py Set

```
USE_L10N = True

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-BR'

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

LANGUAGES = (
    ('pt_BR', 'Portuguese'),
)
```

4) Run following commands

```
$ django-admin makemessages -l pt_BR -i env
$ django-admin compilemessages -l pt_BR
```

5) Then update required translated text in `locale > pt_BR > LC_MESSAGES > django.po` then again run

```
$ django-admin compilemessages -l pt_BR
```

Comment: so why is the language code "pt-BR" but the folder name for the translation files is "pt_BR"?